# Python Websockets: AttributeError: 'Connect' object has no attribute 'send'

Tags: python, websocket, client

So, I'm creating a websocket client in python, this is the code

```
import websockets

ws = websockets.connect('ws://localhost:6789')

ws.send('asdf')
```

but whenever I tried to run it, it says

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "client.py", line 5, in <module>
    ws.send('asdf')
AttributeError: 'Connect' object has no attribute 'send'
```

Answer (score 1):

The object you have is the connector object which should be connected, similar to having a file descriptor that you need to open or use the "with" syntax.
try:

```
import websockets

async with websockets.connect('ws://localhost:6789') as ws:
    await ws.send('asdf')
```

Comment: ok will try later